# Laravel migrations with multiple sites and DB's on my homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

So I have set up my homestead so that I have two sites with two separate DB's. I can go to both sites separately when I run homestead up and can make changes to one site separately from the other. But when I try to do a simple migration of the in box create_user_table on the 2nd site it says there is nothing to migrate. I run migrate:status and it says both migrations (create_user_table and create_passworde_resets_table) have been made but nothing is showing up in 2nd my database.

I have a hunch that my 2nd site is still pointing to the first DB because when I run migrate:rollback I get a message that a class from my other project can't be found. How can I point my 2nd project at my 2nd DB?

p.s. I know the 2nd DB exists because I used sequel pro to login to my VM and I see that both DB's are there

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I had to go into my .env file and edit the DB_DATABASE variable to the proper database name.